unable umount/mount ntfs drive in ubuntu desktop live CD
I want to clear my windows password because I don't know it anymore; Therefore I want to use the cli "sudo chntpw SAM".
This commands must be execited in the mounted windows ntfs dir with the sam
When I execute "df" in the terminal on live ubutuntu desktop there is no filesystem "/dev/nvme0n1p3" which is the device where my c:/ ntfs windows drive is located.
However this device is mounted in the ubuntu file explorer but does I not find it in the terminal?
This means I cannot execute the chntpw command because I cannot go to SAM dir.
I must umount desktop ntfs device (but how?) en then mount in terminal?

If you find it in ubuntu explorer (files/Nautilus) then click on it to mount it and once in right click to open a terminal.

Maybe some explanation
I talk about running an ubuntu desktop live CD 20.10 on a windows 10 laptop

This question could be better phrased as: "How do I list all of the mounted filesystems on the system".
To go about finding the ntfs disk, you can cat out the contents of /etc/mtab
cat /etc/mtab

Look for the windows drive and it's mountpoint.
(You can ls the contents of any mount you don't recognize and examine its contents if you aren't sure which mountpoint is the one you want.)
If you still want to unmount the disk to mount it elsewhere,
sudo umount /where/the/ntfs/drive/is_mounted

